# How to convert 16 bit image to 8 bit in OpenCV C++

Tags: opencv

I'm stuck at using `connectedComponents` function.

```
const uint16_t* depth_frame_data = (const uint16_t*)(rs2_get_frame_data(frame, &e));
Mat image(Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT), CV_16UC1, (void *)depth_frame_data, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
threshold(image, image_th, one_meter, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

I thought this is enough for `connectedComponents`, but i just realized i should input binary Matrix :

```
Mat image_bin(image_th, true);
image_bin.convertTo(image_bin, CV_8U, 0.00390625);
```

But when i build it,

> OpenCV(3.4.2) Error: Assertion failed ...

Comment: post the failed assertion please...

Comment: well thanks for attention but actually i got solution! should i delete this question or just leave it?

Comment: leave it and accept your own answer. If possible you should add to the answer, why the first version failed and what's the difference. I don't see a real difference in the usage of the .convertTo function, so the answer wouldn't help me here and there is probably something else going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by using another function.

```
Mat image_grayscale = image.clone();
image_grayscale.convertTo(image_grayscale, CV_8U, 1 / 256.0);
```

guess there was a problem with cloning

Comment: Surely there must be a better way than this? This will convert every pixel from 16-bit integer to a double, multiply by `1/256.0` and then convert back to 8-bit integer. Integer division by 256 followed by direct integer to integer conversion would be far faster.

Answer (score 0):

To convert 8bit image to 16bit image

```
image_16bit = image_8bit * 257 ;
```

For 16bit image to 8bit image

```
image_8bit = image_16bit / 257 ;
```

I hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will make the picture about 10-20% darker